(p, q) ∈ S only if p ∧ q is a tautology. Assessing the relation S.
This is the first time I come across a question that combines relations and logic.

It is said that: “Let $$ be a relation, which is defined on the set of propositional formulas as follows
$$
\left(,\right) \in \quad {\bf iff}\quad   \wedge \  \mbox{is a}\ tautology”.
$$
I need to assess if $S$ is reflexive, symmetric and/or transitive.

For $ \wedge $ to be a tautology, obviously both $p$ and $q$ need to be true.

So, that means that the only thing included in $S$ is $\left(T,T\right)$?
And what does that mean about its reflexivity, for example? If $S$ is defined on the entire set of propositions, does that mean that since $\left(F,F\right)$ is not included, therefore $S$ is not reflexive? Or for reflexivity, we only care about $\left(p,p\right)$ and $\left(q,q\right)$, so we have two kinds of $\left(T,T\right) \in $?
I have similar confusions about the rest that I need to answer.


(T,T) is not the only thing in S, because among propositional formulas, T is not the only tautology. For non-reflexivity, your counterexample (F,F) is fine if $F$ is some propositional formula whose truth value is always "false".

This question is similar to: Proving that a relation is or is not an equivalence relation. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@TankutBeygu This question is clearly different. No need to edit it.

@TankutBeygu  How is this question similar to the question you site?  The relation there is on non-zero integers and the relation is when products are positive. This relation is on logical statements and the relations is was there conjunction is a tautology.  How could the answers to that question be of any use here.

@fleablood see my answer below

You don't ever need to figure out in what ways $p\wedge q$ could be a tautology.
It is sufficient to point out that, defined by $\wedge, S$ satisfies all three conditions to be an equivalence relation.
Take $S$ as partioning all the propositional formulas into an equivalence class of all tautologies, and thus, an equivalence class of all non-tautologies. Hence,

If $p$ and $q$ are tautologies, then $p$ is related to $q$ by being
tautology, i.e., $(p,q)\in S$ and $p\wedge q$ is a tautology.
If $p\wedge q$ is a tautology, then $p$ and $q$ can only be
tautologies and $(p,q)\in S$.

So,
$(p,p)\in S$ for reflexivity,
$(p,q)\in S\iff (q,p)\in S$ for symmetry,
$(p,q)\in S\mbox{ and }(q, r)\in S\implies (p, r)\in S$ for transivity
immediately follows.
As extra information: $(p, q)$ can be $(\top, \top), (\neg\bot,\neg\bot)$ and any compound formula equivalent to these.

Nitpicking issue regarding reflexivity: does an atomic formula $p$ belong to "the set of propositional formulas"? If yes, what about $p \land p$ for $p$ atomic?

Atomic formulas are in non-$S$, but note that non-$S$ also forms an equivalence class. Hence, $(p, p)\in\bar{S}$ as well as $(p,\neg p)\in\bar{S}$ and $(\neg p, p)\in\bar{S}$, satisfying reflexivity.

But then $(p,p) \notin S$ for p atomic, that means that S in not reflexive.

I think you unnecessarily complicate matters. We divide the set of propositional formulas into two disjoint subsets, like in modular arithmetic. In one subset, there are all and only tautologies, in the other, non-tautologies. Like, say, if $p$ is a tautology $p\equiv 1, (mod, tautology)$  and $p\wedge p$ is a tautology, else  $p\equiv 0, (mod, tautology)$ and $p\wedge p$ is not a tautology.

@MauroALLEGRANZA you might be making an elementary mistake :)
